# Can I use a power cord from a computer for an amp

Tags: amplifier, wire, watts

I rented an amp for a keyboard but didn't take the power cord. I'm pretty sure a regular computer or computer monitor cord will fit. Is it safe? The amp says on it 175 watts. Also I have a power cord from an electric kettle, which is probably a lot more powerful but really short.

- Is it safe to use one of those?
- In general, how do you determine how many watts a wire can handle?

Also, if I need something else, where can I get one quickly?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the cords:

- can mate with the amp properly (usually, since those are largely standardized)
- have the correct polarity (can be quickly checked with a multimeter)
- can handle the current (1.5A for 120V, 0.8A for 240V)